# "GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me 401 (Unauthorized)": why I cannot access the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: reactjs, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

I want my React Application (that is hosted at Azure Web App Service) to get the basic logged user information, but I am receiving the following error:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Here are some configuration of my App:

**Identity provider info:**

[image]

**Permissions Info:**
[image]

My code is:

```
// **** Imports in general 

const getUserInformation = async () => {

  //#region - Constants and variables
  var response_token_store = null;
  var data_token_store = null;
  var response_user_info = null;
  var data_user_info = null;
  //#endregion

  try {
    // TOKEN STORE
    response_token_store = await fetch("/.auth/me", {
      method: "GET",
      body: null,
    });

    // RESPONSE ERROR
    if (!response_token_store.ok) {
      throw new Error("Get request failed!");
    }

    // RESPONSE - JSON
    data_token_store = await response_token_store.json();


    // Microsoft Graph API (user info)

    response_user_info = await fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", {
      // mode: "cors",
      method: "GET",
      body: null,
      headers: {
        Host: "graph.microsoft.com",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${data_token_store[0].access_token.toString()}`,
      },
    });

    // RESPONSE ERROR|
    if (!response_user_info.ok) {
      throw new Error("Get request failed!");
    }

    // RESPONSE - JSON
    data_user_info = await response_user_info.json();
    
    // Catch
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error (Unable to get user information):");
    console.log(error);
  }
};

// Component
function App() {

  // If is not in the localhost
  if (apiURI !== "http://localhost:5000") {
    getUserInformation();
  } else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("USER_INFO", "");
  }
 
  return ( ** not necessary ** );
}

// Default export
export default App;
```

Please, if I can provide any other information, just tag me.

Comment: What are the scopes you're defining while acquiring token for Graph API?

Comment: Sorry, how can I see this scopes?

Answer (score 0):

the answer was inside the tenant AAD -> App Registrations -> Your Web App -> App Registrations.

I needed to activate the below check-boxes.

[image]